# Localized at $p$ integral representations of finite elementary $p$-groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

Let $C_p$ be a cyclic group of prime order $p$. 
Let $F=C_p^n=C_p\times\dots\times C_p$ ($n$ times).
I would like to to classify finite dimensional representations of $F$ over ${\mathbb{Z}}$.
However, if $M\subset N$ are two such integral representations and $M$ is of finite *prime-to-$p$* index in $N$, I call $M$ and $N$ *$p$-equivalent*.
This is probably the same as to say that $M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} {\mathbb{Z}}_{(p)}$ is isomorphic to $N\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} {\mathbb{Z}}_{(p)}$,
where ${\mathbb{Z}}_{(p)}$ is the ring of fractions $a/b$ with $a,b\in{\mathbb{Z}}$, $b$ is prime to $p$. I would like to classify integral representations of $C_p^n$ up to $p$-equivalence.

**Question.** What is known or can be said on the integral representations, in particular, on the indecomposable integral representations, of $F=C_p^n$ with respect to this equivalence relation?

For example, in the case $F=C_p$, I think there are only three indecomposable integral representations up to $p$-equivalence: the 1-dimensional trivial representation, the permutation $p$-dimensional representation ${\mathbb{Z}}[C_p]$, and the $(p-1)$-dimensional representation ${\mathbb{Z}}[C_p]/{\mathbb{Z}}$ (where ${\mathbb{Z}}$ is embedded into ${\mathbb{Z}}[C_p]$ diagonally). 
Is that correct? 
What can be said in the case  $F=C_p\times C_p$ ?

Comment: There are infinitely many isomorphism types for $n >1.$ The number of isomorphism types is actually at least $1 + 2h_{p}$ when $n =1$, where $h_{p}$ is the class number of $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ and $\omega$ is a primitive $p$-th root of unity. For references, see for example https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mmj/1028998908.

Comment: There are infinitely many isomorphism classes for $n>2$. Anyway, thank you for the link, I did not know it.

Comment: That is the cyclic case. I the non-cyclic elementary Abelia case, (which you have to look further back for, working from the references in Jones' paper), there are infinitely many isomorphism classes when $ n >1.$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson You are right! Thank you!